# Need to redirect to sign-oidc page after logout

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, identityserver4, adfs

In Client application i have set below configuration and in postLogoutRedirectUri parameter set as sign-oidc url but still able to redirect to singin-oidc url and Auth service i have used using ADFS , openid connect and identity server using .Net 6.

```
 config: {
        authority: 'https://localhost:6001', 
        clientId: 'Test',
        **postLogoutRedirectUri: 'http://localhost:6269/signin-oidc',**      
        redirectUrl:'http://localhost:6269/signin-oidc',        
        scope: 'openid profile',
        responseType: 'code',
        autoUserInfo: true,
        silentRenew: true,
        useRefreshToken: true,
        logLevel: LogLevel.Debug        
      },
```

how can i redirect to signin-oidc page ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable both frontchannel_logout support and session supported to true.
Example:
[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/development/ad-fs-logout-openid-connect)

Then make sure your ADFS Server implements the allow url by

```
Set-AdfsClient -TargetIdentifier <id> -LogoutUri http://localhost:5000/logout
```

If this is a server application

```
Set-AdfsServerApplication -TargetIdentifier <id> -LogoutUri http://localhost:5000/logout
```

So you can change your URL to something like this

```
https://localhost:6269/adfs/oauth2/logout?id_token_hint=<current_Id_Token>&post_logout_redirect_uri=http://localhost:6269
```